# Как создать массив Radiobutton?

Tags: vb.net, radiobutton

Есть форма. На ней расположено 4 Radiobutton
Я пробую создать массив из них:

```
Dim radioButtons As RadioButton {
 RadioButton1,
 RadioButton2,
 RadioButton3,
 RadioButton4
}
```

Потом пытаюсь пройти по массиву в цикле:

```
For i = 0 To ubound(radiobuttons)
   radioButtons(i).Text = ...
Next
```

Но в в цикле срабатывает ошибка.
**Как правильно реализовать эту идею?**

Comment: А в какой версии фреймворка у вас такой код? У меня в 2015 студии, даже объявить таким образом массив не получилось, не похоже это на массив...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так.

```
    Dim buttons As RadioButton() = New RadioButton(3) {
            RadioButton1,
            RadioButton2,
            RadioButton3,
            RadioButton4}

    For i = 0 To UBound(buttons)
        radioButtons(i).Text = "text"
    Next
```

Но я бы сделал так, списки гораздо удобнее массивов.

```
    Dim radioButtons As New List(Of RadioButton)

    radioButtons.Add(RadioButton1)
    radioButtons.Add(RadioButton2)
    radioButtons.Add(RadioButton3)
    radioButtons.Add(RadioButton4)

    For Each button As RadioButton In radioButtons
        button.Text = "text"
    Next
```